# How do I execute master data sql script using database project on build

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, database-project

I want to insert master data automatically. (executing sql scripts automatically)

`I tried this using database project using pre-deployment script.`

But my application is deployed on windows azure.

Is there any limitation for this?

or should I go with `database project and pre-deployment project`

> How do i execute .sql script automatically when I build my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really tricky. As of my knowledge You can't execute a .sql script automatically when you build your project.

Alternatively you can write a console application EXE for roll out your scripts, and then the call the Console app EXE in post-build events of visual studio, so that each and every successive build the EXE get triggered. 
So automatically your scripts are executed via this EXE after every successive build.

Comment: ok great help can you give me any link about how to do this approach?

Comment: For How to use Pre-build and Post-build Events in Visual Studio, follow these links.                     http://miteshsureja.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-use-pre-build-and-post-build.html                                     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: thanks is there any other way to insert master data using auto execute?

Comment: No. But you can use a Set Up User Interface to run your scripts. Anyway this setup page UI also comes part of your application. You have to write codes to roll out your script.

Comment: can't I use pre build event and execute my sql file or predeploymeny script ?

Comment: You can. But all we want after a successive build only we roll out our scripts. But its up to you.